# How to add new columns whose names come from another tables value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to add around 200 columns on the database table i.e. column1 has 200 entries. I need all those 200 entries to be the column names on another table.

For Eg.

Table1 has

> C1  C2
>  10 xyz
>  11 abc
>  12 pqr

Now, table2 should have all the columns of the above C2 column

> C1 xyz abc pqr
>  50 '12' '13' '88'
>  51 '99' '12' '11'
>  52 '12'
>   '13' '12'

So, basically the values in C2 of table1 are now the column names of table i.e. xyz, abc and pqr from column1 have now become the column names of  table2.

Is this possible or do we have to add 200 column names by manually typing only.

Comment: That's dynamic SQL. 1. step: retrieve the names from table1. 2. step build a create table statement based on that (with a programming language, e.g. PHP, C# or Java). 3. step: execute the statement. Done.

Comment: Hmm. sounds like a good idea. Wil try it now. Will let you know if it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, yes it worked. Thanks a lot man. Solutions are always simple.